# Action listening for container itself and sub buttons

Tags: codenameone

I'm stuck. I would like to find out which component a user was pointing at when an `ActionEvent` is passed to a `LeadComponent`.

In my case I want to know if a user pressed on any point in a `Container` or at a specific `Button` which is contained by that `Container`. But the `LeadComponent` and that `Button` are not the same, and shouldn't be. Some text have to get copied to clipboard if the user taps on the green box, and if pressed on the map button another functionality should be triggered instead (see image below).
Unfortunately neither `ActionEvent.getActualComponent()` nor `ActionEvent.getSource()` returns that `Button` when it comes to the events received by the LeadComponent, and the `ActionListener`, I added to the map Button, doesn't receive any events at all. Is there any solution?

[image: green box with map button]

After I got to know that `subButton.setBlockLead(true)` is the right call to do here, I still had the problem that the sub button doesn't receive any action events. As I checked test cases, I found out that the issue is linked to an underlaying `Component` (in my case it's a `MapComponent` but it also could be a plain `Container`). The sub Button does not receive any events in that case:

[image: Subbutton does not receive any events]

this does not work for example (`follow` does not receive any events):

```
    Container current = f.getContentPane();

    // box with leading behavior
    Button lead = new Button("Leading");
    Button follow = new Button("Following");
    Label justData = new Label("Just Data");
    Container cnt = FlowLayout.encloseIn(lead, justData, follow);
    cnt.setUIID("ToastBar"); //to emphasize the lead area
    cnt.setLeadComponent(lead);
    follow.setBlockLead(true);

    lead.addActionListener(e -> Log.p("Lead pressed"));
    follow.addActionListener(e -> Log.p("Follow pressed"));

    //child for LayeredLayout (positioning the box)
    Container child = BorderLayout.centerAbsolute(cnt);

    //LayeredLayout with dummy container and the specific child on top
    cnt = LayeredLayout.encloseIn(new Container(), child);

    current.add(cnt);
```

[image: layered layout issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude a specific component from the lead component hierarchy by using [unleading](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/unleading-mutating-accordion.html):

```
delete.setBlockLead(true);
```

This works for me and only sends the right events:

```
Button lead = new Button("Leading");
Button follow = new Button("Following");
Label justData = new Label("Just Data");
Container cnt = FlowLayout.encloseIn(lead, justData, follow);
cnt.setLeadComponent(lead);
follow.setBlockLead(true);

lead.addActionListener(e -> Log.p("Lead pressed"));
follow.addActionListener(e -> Log.p("Follow pressed"));
current.add(cnt);
```

Comment: thanks to that call the leading doesn't happen anymore, but still that button does not receive any events. My code:        `navigateToBtn.setBlockLead(true); navigateToBtn.addActionListener((e) -> onNavigateToPressed(e));`

Comment: but that button does receive events, when I remove the LeadComponent from the Container and I set: `navigateToBtn.setBlockLead(false);`

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a test case? It's possible that something in the hierarchy you used triggered unleading to misbehave

Comment: I guess you marked something incorrectly. The code above works for me. I suggest not using the GUI builder as you might have clicked something that you shouldn't have by mistake

Comment: yes your code works. But as I was trying to explain, it does not if the `Container` with the LeadComponent is part of a `LayeredLayout`. I put a code snippet as example concerning this.

Comment: It works fine in a layered layout too. A layered layout stretches its content over available space so you effectively created a component that takes up the entire form (which you can easily see in the Component Inspector). Wrap the content in a flow layout or any other layout to achieve positioning this is even demonstrated in the layered layout JavaDoc

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean Shai. To demonstrate my issue I put a screen cast in my question post. Maybe you might tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong there. My `follow` Button just doesn't receive any events. I also noticed that by pressing any other Component like `lead` or `justData` there is also no event fired. Everything works fine if that Container is not in a `LayeredLayout`.

Comment: In order to not getting misunderstood. I don't want to have the LayeredLayout leading click events but its child `Container` which in turn has a sub button. That sub button should handle its own action events.

Comment: Set the color of the lead container so you will see where the component is placed: `parentLeadContainer.getAllStyle().setBgTransparency(100)` once you understand that it should be obvious why this is always clicked. I suggest looking at the layered layout sample I mentioned

Comment: actually I already set `cnt.setUIID("ToastBar");` which has a dark BG color (see the code in my screen cast). By reducing the bgTransparency I don't get the point. That container is stretched over the whole form as expected. But why is this affecting the lead behavior? I mean, when I use the Container from your code, it's working as it should. The whole container except the `follow` Button leads the clicks, and `follow` receives its own events. But when I put the same Container as child in a LayeredLayout the behavior gets broken.

Comment: The Container still does lead the clicks (as expected) but `follow` doesn't receive anything (even the other components don't trigger events).. I'm really confused. Do you think, concerning my code, it's an expected behavior that "Follow pressed" is never printed?

Comment: Note: this happens if and only if there are layers under that Container!

Comment: If you set a lead container on the entire form then all the clicks anywhere within the lead will go to that lead button. That would effectively block the entire form. You need to set the lead on a container that accepts the portion of the form where you want the lead to apply.

Comment: but I already did that. The leadComponent is only set on the FlowLayout (I created it as you did) which has that sub button as child. That's why I'm thinking that there seems to be a bug in the lead behavior, when that Container with the leadComponent is overlying other Containers. In that case lead blocking doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: as a simple example:
when I put only that FlowLayout in the LayeredLayout, everything works as expected:
`cnt = LayeredLayout.encloseIn( cnt);`
but if there is something beneath, the button doesn't receive any events:
`cnt = LayeredLayout.encloseIn( new Container() ,cnt);`

Comment: The lead component should be set on the sub container not on the flow layout which wrapped it for positioning. Review the example from the layered layout javadoc.

Comment: which sub container do you mean? There are just 2 containers in my example. The one is the `LayeredLayout` and the other that `FlowLayout` (and actually a third one, which is just a dummy to demonstrate the issue). I also checked the javadoc you refered to multiple times, the only thing I could see as solution is to use insets and references to position my Components. It's also not a portable solution. But I think you don't mean that? If it's just a change of a few lines could you please provide me an example based on my code? Otherwiese it's time for me to surrender..

Comment: Note: it's crucial that the LayeredLayout exists since I want to display a none-modal message box on top of a MapContainer.

Comment: The first example with the X. If the layered layout isn't a lead component then it won't grab pointer events... A container below it in the hierarchy can position the component to its "real position" and only the container within **THAT** can be a lead

Comment: well I changed the code as you described so that the child of the LayeredLayout is not a lead container anymore but a child of that is one. I checked the example with the X. It still doesn't work. Actually my problem is not that the leading doesn't work (because the leading does work), my problem is that the lead blocking button doesn't receive its own events. Thanks for your time Shai, and sorry that I couldn't fix it despite your help.

Comment: Can you modify my sample code so it reproduces your issue. Please don't use the GUI builder just edit my code and recreate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the patience, I think I see the issue although I'm not too sure about the fix I came up with... We'll push out the fix next week and see if it solves the issue.